# How to solve this equation: $\left( 1 + \frac1x\right)^{x+1} = \left(1 +\frac1{1999}\right)^{1999}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the equation:
    $$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1} = \left(1 + \frac{1}{1999}\right)^{1999}$$

If the sum of all real $x$ that satisfy the above equation is $S$, then find the number of trailing zeroes in the value of $\lfloor S/5 \rfloor$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.
Please help me to solve this question.

Comment: It's $x=-2000$ . Hope you can continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $f(x):=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$ may not be a real number for $x\in[-1,0]$.  However, for $x\in (-\infty,-1)$, $f(x)$ increases to $\text{e}$ as $x$ decreases to $-\infty$.  Hence, for $x<-1$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=t$ has at most one solution, and there exists exactly one solution if and only if $0<t<\text{e}$.  From user90369's comment, we see that $x=-2000$ is the unique solution to $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{1999}\right)^{1999}$ with the extra condition that $x<-1$.

Next, for $x>0$, $f(x)$ decreases to $\text{e}$ as $x$ increases to $+\infty$.  Hence, for $x>0$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=t$ has at most one solution, and there exists exactly one solution if and only if $t>\text{e}$.  This proves that $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{1999}\right)^{1999}$ has no solution with $x>0$.

Now, let $x\in(-1,0)$.  Only for $x=-\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$, and $q$ is odd, we have that $f(x)$ is real.  For such $x=\frac{p}{q}$, $f(x)>0$ if and only if $p$ is odd.  That is, if $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{1999}\right)^{1999}$, then $x=-\frac{2m-1}{2n-1}$ for some integers $m,n>0$ (with $m<n$ and $\gcd(2m-1,2n-1)=1$).  However, we obtain
$$f\left(-\frac{2m-1}{2n-1}\right)=\left(\frac{2(n-m)}{2m-1}\right)^{ \frac{2(n-m)}{2n-1}}\,.$$
Note that this number is a rational number if both $2(n-m)$ and $2m-1$ are perfect $(2n-1)$-st powers of integers.  Since $2(n-m)=b^{2n-1}$ for some integer $b>0$ and $2(n-m)>1$, we get $b\geq 2$, whence
$$2n-1>2(n-m)=b^{2n-1}\geq 2^{2n-1}>2n-1\,,$$ which is absurd.  That is, for $x\in(-1,0)$ such that $f(x)$ is a positive real number, $f(x)$ is an irrational number. Hence, $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{1999}\right)^{1999}$ has no solution with $x\in[-1,0]$ either.

In conclusion, the only real solution to $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{1999}\right)^{1999}$ is $x=-2000$.   That is, $S=-2000$.

Comment: All right, but it would be a little cleaner (and we'd get the single solution immediately) if we first write $1+\frac{1}{x}=(\frac{x}{x+1})^{-1}=(1-\frac{1}{x+1})^{-1}$ and we substitute $u=-(x+1)$

Comment: @leonbloy Nothing will be cleaner.  Even if you consider $\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)^u$ with $u:=-(x+1)$, you still have to think about the case where $u<-1$, $-1<u<0$, and $u>0$, with only the case $u>0$ leading to a solution $u=1999$.  A proof, using $u$ instead of $x$, should be just as messy.

Answer (score 1):

This is pure manipulation:

$$\left(1 +\frac{1}{1999}\right)=\frac{2000}{1999}=\left(\frac{-2000}{-1999}\right)=\left(\frac{-1999}{-2000}\right)^{-1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{-2000}\right)^{-1}$$

$$\left(1 +\frac{1}{1999}\right)^{1999}=\left(1+\frac{1}{-2000}\right)^{-1999}=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$$

S0: $x=-2000$

Comment: You have found a solution. You have not proved that it's the only one